# Generic Repository pattern with ThenIncludes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

My solution has several layers, one of them is the `DataAccess` layer where I've implemented the repository pattern.

My main focus is that `EntityFramework` **is only referenced** in the `DataAccess` layer.

I had the need to include relations on my queries so I adapted my querie methods to receive the `Includes` as an input.

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();

    if (includes != null)
    {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query,
                  (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Example use:

```
// Books :: ICollection<Book>
var query = _repository.AsQueryable(e => e.Books);
```

Using the example above how can I, for example, include the `Book -> Author` relation in the query? The property `Books` is a collection therefore I cannot reference the `Author` property.

Example: `.AsQueryable(e => e.Books, e => Books.Author)` OR `.AsQueryable(e => e.Books.ChildInclude(b => b.Author))`

Comment: Maybe you should first explain why you can't now.

Comment: @GertArnold Simply because `Books` is a collection and I can't reference the `Author` property

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: Looks like by exposing(leaking) Entity framework queryable, you are trying to build own "ORM" on top of existing one :)

Comment: One option - treat DbContext as generic repository, because you are already trying to use your generic repository as DbContext ;).  Second option - do not expose queryable or query expressions, but instead accept some custom query types(commands or requests) and inside repository generate query based on that type and return "materialised" collection as a result (see Specification pattern)

Answer (score 2):

> My main focus is that EntityFramework is only referenced in the DataAccess layer.

The only safe way to accomplish this is that I can recommend is that you define a boundary between your code that must be isolated from knowledge of EF and the code that can be aware of EF. This means that only materialized DTOs or non-entity models travel across this boundary. This would generally be applicable in cases where you want multiple consumers to be accessing data in an isolated and identical way. (I.e. a web site + API) Even then this imposes trade-offs for flexibility and performance. That boundary normally wouldn't be the repository, but a service which can be aware of EF, manage the DbContext scope, (via Unit of Work, or managing when `SaveChanges()` is called, etc.) access a Repository that leverages `IQueryable<TEntity>`, then projects results into materialized `List<TDTO>` or `TDO` instances for the consumers.

Passing entities outside of the scope of the DBContext they are tracked by leads to all kinds of complexity and problems within systems. This means designing a separation layer that returns DTOs or `IEnumerable<TDTO>` rather than `IQueryable<TEntity>` or even `IEnumerable<TEntity>`. Any code that accepts entities should always have a complete entity graph, or a complete-able entity graph. (Lazy load-able) Bug conditions are ripe when functions accepting entity graphs might, or might not get references or all properties populated, and guessing whether some fetched or constructed entity is "complete enough" to pass to an existing method.

If this abstraction is merely "highly desired" to satisfy a personal preference, or some uncertain concern about a future requirement that might require you to replace EF with some other mechanism, my advice would be simply "Don't".  By implementing patterns to abstract code from EF you are imposing absolute performance constraints and usually significant complexity into your system for no immediate benefit. Leveraging `IQueryable` allows your code to build efficient and performant queries against the data layer. Materializing objects to pass back to a consuming layer will mean a lot of either very similar code, or very complex code to handle filtering, eager loading, projection, sorting, and pagination, and generally return far more data than a more direct method would return.

Eager loading can be facilitated using magic strings, or expressions. Filtering and sorting can be facilitated by expressions as well. However, a big caveat of developing complex expression-based abstractions is that while this may isolate calling code from EF references, it still doesn't isolate that code from EF-specific rules. For instance those expressions need knowledge of and obey EF rules such as not calling functions or anything that ultimately cannot be converted down to SQL.

Abstractions like this often lead to performance issues that reinforce the desire to later replace EF with another ORM or data access method due to performance issues. It becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy.